# Compression of Database using FP trees

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, compression, data-mining, lossless-compression

I have a dataset of around 200 MB, containing only integers. My goal is to use FP-trees to compress this dataset and reduce the final output file size. This is for academic purposes so I can't use zipping software and restricted to FP-trees. The size of the output file is determined by the count of integers in the output and the size of the associated mapping table. To illustrate, consider this example:

```
    T1 - 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
    T2 - 1, 2, 3, 4, 6
    T3 - 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7
    T4 - 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
```

With a mapping like:

```
{
    10 : {1, 2, 3, 4},
    11 : {5, 7},
}
```

The transformed dataset becomes:

```
    T1 - 10, 5
    T2 - 10, 6
    T3 - 10, 11
    T4 - 10, 11, 6
```

However, alternative mappings are possible, like:

```
    {10: (1, 2), 11: (3, 4, 5), 12: (1, 2, 3), 13: (4, 5)}
```

I've successfully implemented the FP-tree algorithm to identify frequent itemsets along with their counts. However, due to the significant time required for constructing an FP-tree on large datasets, I've divided the dataset into smaller sections for compression.

My main objective is to convert each transaction into a set of keys from the mapping, with the aim of reducing the overall size. However, the difficulty lies in identifying segments within each transaction that can be replaced with a key to achieve effective size reduction. Therefore, I'm looking for effective strategies or heuristics that can assist in making these selections and optimizing the compression process. I welcome any insights or recommendations you may have to help tackle this challenge.

Comment: You could build a trie for your mapping, then as you go over the file, every time you reach the end of an entry, you replace the block with said entry mapping. That being said it would be possible to create some nasty set where this will fail spectacularly - hence a question: what is more important, speed or final compression ratio?