# Automating Support Calculation for Efficient FP-Tree Based Database Compression

Tags: database, algorithm, data-structures, data-mining

I'm currently working on compressing a transactional database using the FP-tree algorithm. While adjusting the support threshold, I've encountered a trade-off: setting a very low support value results in excessive computation time, whereas a higher support value yields quicker processing but generates patterns with small sizes (e.g., 2 or 3).

The dataset contains transactions, each comprising only integer values, as illustrated below:

```
    T1 - 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
    T2 - 1, 2, 3, 4, 6
    T3 - 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7
    T4 - 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
```

I've tried binary search but it takes too much time if I try on some value having very low support.
My objective is to automate the process of calculating the optimal support threshold based on the characteristics of the data. I need an heuristic based approach for this. How can I determine an appropriate support value that strikes a balance between computation time and resulting pattern sizes? Are there any specific techniques, heuristics, or best practices that I could leverage to dynamically set the support threshold for FP-tree compression? I'm seeking guidance and insights to efficiently handle this challenge. Thank you in advance for any advice you can provide!

Comment: How does thisquestion differ form https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76918946/compression-of-database-using-fp-trees ?